# Hyperledger-fabric blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I`m really new at hyperledger-fabric and I want to build my own application based on this technology and framework also, but have some spaces in my knowledge(
What information stored in block chain of hyperledger fabric?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are new to blockchain and the way it works, I recommend to understand the basic concept of that technology first. The Hyperledger Fabric Documentation provides a first overview of how it works:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/blockchain.html

When you got the basic understanding of blockchains, you can setup your own development environment:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/getting_started.html

With that, you can build your first network...

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/build_network.html

... and your first application

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html

Answer (score 0):

Blockchain is a technology that works like a ledger. In fact, it works like a distributed ledger, where every participant in the Blockchain holds a copy.'

What is ledger in Hyperledger fabric?
It is like a book that holds the record of transactions. It consists of two parts:- world state and transactions logs.
In world state, it holds the current state/value of set of ledger states.
In transaction logs, it store the transactions that occurred to reach the current state.
These transactions in transaction logs are collected inside a block that are appended to the Blockchain.